# Socket connect timeouts differ between networks

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I have a rather interesting problem. We have 2 networks at work that are physical duplicates of each other (network A and network B). They just run on different subnets.

I am working on some fault tolerance improvements for our devices that cluster with each other on the network. One of the test cases that I am exercising is the behaviour of these devices when a misconfiguration is introduced. For example, lets say I have two devices with the following interface configurations:

**Device X**
IP: 10.200.234.127
Subnet Mask: 255.255.254.0
Default Gateway: 10.200.234.1

**Device Y**
IP: 10.200.234.127
Subnet Mask: 255.255.254.0
Default Gateway: 10.200.234.1

These 2 devices discover each other via the broadcast of cluster heartbeats. The heartbeats contain the devices ip address, etc which allows them to then establish communication with each other. Pretty standard stuff. Now, lets say I introduce a network misconfiguration such that one of these devices is configured for a different sunbet:

**Device X**
IP: 192.168.1.115
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1

What happens here is that both devices still learn about each other from the cluster broadcasts (they are physically connected together on the same switch). However, as you would expect, they cannot communicate with each other as expected. However, I am seeing some strange behaviour with respect to connect timeouts when these devices attempt to communicate with each other. For example, if the devices are connected on network A, the connection attempts timeout within a few seconds which is great. Now, if I place both devices on network B I see a completely different behaviour. On network B, the connect() calls to establish socket connections between the devices do not fail quickly. Rather, they fall into this backoff and retransmit cycle that takes 189 seconds to finally give up ( retransmits at 3, 6, 12, 24, 48, and 96 seconds as verified with wireshark).

So what I am wondering is, why does the connect() call fail so rapidly in network A and not in network B. I have tried using blocking sockets and a call to connect() as well as non-blocking sockets and a call to connect() followed by a call to select(). In both cases I cannot get the connect to give up any sooner than 189 seconds. I know that I can impose a shorter timeout in the call to select and give up much sooner but that is not the point here. I am trying to understand what could possibly be different on these 2 networks that is causing this issue.

Comment: Firewalls may reject TCP segments without replying anything, so that the host connecting will just keep trying...

Comment: Hmm ... in the case of network A when the timeout occurs immediately, I do not actually see any packets leave the device. So perhaps the question is why in network A I don't see any packets while on network B I do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should give more addresses? It's not clear exactly what the IPs are.

My guess is that:

- In the slow case you're getting ARP failures (no response because target has incorrect netmask)
- In the fast case you're getting a routing failure. If the host has an incorrect smaller netmask it won't even attempt ARPs.

Please try to strace blocking sockets, error code should be different.

Comment: Thank you for jogging my memory about the arp side of things. It didn't even occur to me that there might actually be a device sitting in my 10.200.234.0/16 network that had the IP 192.168.1.1 which is what I chose as the gateway IP for my static device configuration. Again, the idea was to pick a configuration that would completely fail. However, once I captured all of the arp packets it was immediately obvious that some frickin device is on the network with the IP 192.168.1.1. So this was the source of all of the timeout trouble. Thanks again cdleonard.